# Set of subclass not matching Set of superclass

Tags: java, inheritance, set

Let's say I have two classes:

```
public class Bike {}
public class MountainBike extends Bike {}
```

When I create a method as follows, it throws no errors:

```
Bike mountainBike = new MountainBike();
// method signature is addBike(Bike bike); 
addBike(mountainBike);
```

But if I try the following:

```
Set<MountainBike> bikes = new HashSet<MountainBike>();
// method signature is addBikes(Set<Bike> bikes);
addBikes(bikes);
```

I get an error about method signatures matching incorrectly. How can I create a Set that encompasses sub-classes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want this:

```
addBikes(Set<? extends Bike> bikes)
```

Also, as @Blacklight points out, `Set` itself is an interface, so you can't instantiate it directly (you need to instantiate one of its concrete implementations, e.g. `HashSet`, `LinkedHashSet`, or `TreeSet`).

The key point here is that `Set<MountainBike>` is not a subtype of `Set<Bike>` - in particular, you can add bikes other than mountain bikes to a set of bikes, but not to a set of mountain bikes. As a result, Java prevents you from passing a `Set<MountainBike>` to a method expecting a `Set<Bike>` for reasons of type safety, since you would otherwise be able to add a non-mountain bike to the set within the method without it being flagged by the compiler (it would instead cause a run-time error).

As an additional observation, note that an *immutable* set of mountain bikes would be an *immutable* set of bikes - it's the mutability that causes the problem here. This ties in with the concepts of covariance and contravariance of type parameters that can be expressed in other languages (notably C#).

Comment: This link might be very useful for OP: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - this has fixed my issue. The `Set` is instantiated elsewhere to a `HashSet`. I'll mark this as accepted when the time limit lapses.